# Typescript npm install not working

Tags: npm, installation, typescript

When I run `sudo npm install -g typescript` the only thing that gets installed is `test3`.  This is what I get:

```
$ sudo npm install -g typescript
Password:
test3@1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/test3
$ tsc
-bash: tsc: command not found
```

The Typescript compiler is never installed.  I reinstalled node/npm just now to see if it was an install issue, but that didn't seem to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Run npm install with `--verbose` flag; test3 has nothing to do with TypeScript. Verbose output should help shine a light on where things are breaking down.

Comment: @CSnover Turning up the verbosity helped me realize a directory already named _typescript_ existed in the directory from which I was running `npm install -g typescript`.  That was messing up the command.  When I deleted that dir, the install happened fine.  Thanks.